# count query on save in Django models

Tags: django

I am trying to preform a count query and stamp it into my model on save.

The count only returns 1, no matter how many children related to the parent.

For example:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ......

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        children = Children.objects.filter(parent=self.id).count()
        self.no_of_children = children

        super(Parent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Children(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: ugh some how missed it out. Edited the question

Comment: Separately from your question, think about why you are doing this. Denormalisation is a valid technique, but should be used only when you are sure you have a performance issue. Generally it's better to ask the db to calculate this when you need it, eg via aggregation, which is simple to do in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in filtering your queryset. 
Check the following code. (This code assumes that you already have a parent object, in case you dont then this method will not work.)

```
class Parent(models.Model):
......

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        children = Children.objects.filter(parent__id=self.id).count()
        self.no_of_children = children

        super(Parent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Children(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```